# how to get data from php in android app?

Tags: php, android

I am trying to connect my android app to oracle server using php. But now the issue is that how I can get data (that php fetched from server), in my android app using http not json? Like, if my php file is fetching some data from server and then displaying it on screen, then how can i get that in my android app?

Comment: you should make an api that provides json, because parsing html is slower.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1: From your code you should send the GET or POST request to  specific link

```
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
```

Step 2: On the server with php, just check if request came

```
//do some task and print json
print(json_encode($response)
```

Step 3: In your code get response :

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(url));
```

Step 4: manipulate with json

Comment: Is it necessary to use json?

Comment: No, of course not. But if you have big information, for example database whole table, json is faster, comfortable and awesome. thats why I suggested json. You can simply use print method.

Comment: I am not getting that how can i get data from php in android using HttpPost and HttpResponse? Can you help me?

Comment: You are sending the httpPost request to server. The server(with php code) checks if request came. If yes, returning(just printing) the response(with php). In your android code you are getting the response.

Comment: i tried to print http response but it's not that data which i need, it's something else.